# iTunes not changing my app status after i uploaded my iOS app

Tags: ios, itunes

I just uploaded a binary to itunes from Xcode. But when I checked
the iTunes page it says waiting for upload. I do not know why. This
problem happens only after the new UI changes on iTunes side.

Any help that might be appreciated

Comment: This is clearly an Apple issue. I would call Developer Support and speak with a tech. Apple's number is 1 (800) 633-2152. Everytime I've called them with something odd in iTunesConnect they've been able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It may be still processing. Somewhere in the iTunes Connect documentation it says this might take some time. If after 24 hours nothing has changed, I'd recommend you contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and I just uploaded the binary again. Third time it showed up. It takes about 10 min. of processing before you can select the binary for Submitting.